# ASP.Net Session State

Tags: asp.net, session, httpapplication, session-state

I was wondering whether it would be possible to change the sqlConnectionString used for SessionState in ASP.net based upon the domain an application is running on?

A scenario; We have 20 sites running from one application all talking to different databases depending which domain (site) they are browsing from.

When browsing www.domain1.com the application talks to the database 'db1'. The site www.domain2.com on the other hand talks to the database 'db2' etc, thus selecting the relevant content and also spreading the load to each database rather than using one master database to handle all connections for the sites.

An issue that has arisen though - for this setup we use SqlServer mode for the SessionState so all users to all sites sessions are stored in 1 aspstate database, now as the sites get busier / number of sites increase this database comes under increasing strain to handle all the session requests for all the sites and we are starting to get some timeout errors where the connections to this database are bottlenecking.

We can seperate out the sites to from their own application and set up different applications with the same code but within each application set a different Session database in each Web.Config and thus lightening the load. This task would be quite time consuming though and would result in more management in the long term. SO.. I would love to know if it's possible to modify within the code the sqlConnectionString used for SessionState, based upon a domain, before the session object is created? Can we inherit from System.Web.HttpApplication and use the Application_AcquireRequestState event to create the required setup of the HttpSessionState object?

Hopefully this makes sense and that someone can provide some pointers and prove to me that this isn't a pipe dream!

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a big point--putting things in separate databases on the same server isn't going to help things at all if the bottleneck is sql server--it is either SQL running out of headroom or the network running out of bandwidth. I'd try and figure out which one it was before doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue isn't so much that the connections to the database are bottlenecking, its that you are overwhelming the network connection to the database with data from all of the sessions.

By default, the Sql Server state provider simply serializes your data and ships it to the database.  This is VERY inefficient and takes a LONG time to transfer on a fast network.

We solved this problem by going to a custom provider, like [DOTSS](http://dotss.codeplex.com) that compresses session content before shipping it to the database.  The compression rates we see are 80%-90% and the compression time is less than 10ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom session state provider. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) for details. I've never done it, but with a little luck you can wrap the SqlServer session state module and redirect it based on the domain

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, I don't see there is advantage of "I would love to know if it's possible to modify within the code the sqlConnectionString used for SessionState, based upon a domain, before the session object is created" compared to set this in web.config.
- Secondly, I think you need change that connection string setting in App_Start, so all the request will use that changed settings.Application_AcquireRequestState probably too late for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not split up the sites into sperate web applications and use hostheader to differentiate between the web sites.  That way you could easily configure which session database you want your web application to use since each web application would have a seperate web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You could partition your session across different databases by implementing [`IPartitionResolver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ipartitionresolver.aspx), and using a different partition for each domain.

[Here's an example showing how to implement a custom partition resolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163730.aspx#S8). (The example partitions by session ID, but it would be trivial to change it to partition by domain instead.)

Answer (score 0):

We have several dozen development sites whose database connections are handled via the project's main Web.Config.

There is a separate configuration section corresponding to each URL on our intranet (e.g. http://development11, http://development12).  We have SQL instances with a similar naming convention (DEVDB1\SQL1, DEVDB1\SQL2).

Based on the URL configured on the intranet IIS server, the app grabs the appropriate config.  For testing we can easily modify the user, the database server or individual databases utilized for a particular site.